# Issue with deployment using Cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to deploy my worker using wrangler dev or wrangler publish but I am getting this error even though I have already added my account id into the wrangler.toml file like I was instructed to do in the documentation.

**Error: field `account_id` is required to deploy to workers.dev**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are wrangler'ing from the right directory? Are you sure your account_id is correct, and in the correct format in your wrangler.toml? It should be 32 characters long.

Comment: Yes, I am in the right directory and it is the correct account_id, it is 32 characters long and I believe it is in the correct format as i have tried formatting it differently and it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Try redoing wrangler init in a new directory, it fixed it for me.